# Deleting Certain Elements from a Char Array

Tags: c, string

I have a function that strips punctuators from a given string, and makes all of it's contents lower-case:

```
void stripPunctuators(char *str)
{
  int i, j, len = strlen(str);


  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
     if (!isalpha(str[i]))
     {
       for (j = i; j < len; j++)
       {
         str[j] = str[j + 1];
       }
       len--;
     }

     str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
  }
}
```

But for some reason it runs into trouble when I have two non-alpha characters in a row...
Here is my main function:

```
 int main(void)
 {
   char str[50] = "Hello.";

   printf("Before strip: %s\n", str);
   stripPunctuators(str);
   printf("After strip: %s\n", str);

   char str2[50] = "Hello.!";

   printf("Before strip: %s\n", str2);
   stripPunctuators(str2);
   printf("After strip: %s\n", str2);

   return 0;
}
```

Finally, here is my output:

```
Before strip: Hello.
After strip: hello
Before strip: Hello.!
After strip: hello!
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Time to learn [how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and learn [how to use gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Comment: Your inner j loop looks fishy. All you need is a temp variable to the next index in str to where you want to copy the next valid character pointed to by index i. For all non-alpha characters you can just skip the loop iteration with a `continue`.

Comment: @kbr I thought that is what I was doing in my inner j loop. I move every index after the non-alpha char to the right, essentially deleting the non-alpha index from the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may to help to think of a short string such as `a!@b`. Your index variable will iterate over the values `0..3` inclusive due to your use of the `for` loop. Now follow the sequence:

```
0123     <- indexes
----
a!@b     starting point, index = 0
a!@b     index 0 was a, no shift, set index to 1
a@b      index 1 was !, shift, set index to 2 ***
a@b      index 2 was b, no shift, set index to 3, exit loop
```

From that, you should be able to see that shifting the remainder of the string *and* increasing the index will cause the next character to be skipped (see the `***` marker for where things went wrong).

You could fix this by using a loop where the index *isn't* incremented for those times when you do a shift (probably using `while` rather than `for` would be a good idea). That way, a shift-without-increment would leave you re-checking the *same* index, which is the *next* character (due to the shift).

However, doing a full shift of the string remainder every time you want to delete a character is rather inefficient, since there's a good possibility you may need to change those characters again.

You're far better off using a source and destination pointer with something like (pseudo-code):

```
set src and dst to address of first character
while character at src is not end-of-string:
    if character at src is not punctuation:
        set character at dst to be character at src
        increment dst
    increment src
set character at dst to be end-of-string
```

And, if you wanted that in C, it would be along the lines of:

```
void stripPunctuators(char *str) {
    char *src = str;
    char *dst = str;
    while (*src != '\0') {
        if (isalpha(*src)) {
            *dst = *src;  // or combine:
            dst++;        //   "*dst++ = *src"
        }
        src++;
    }
    *dst = '\0';
}
```

> Note that I've used `isalpha` in my code simply because that's the one you used in your original code. Since that will strip more than punctuation (digits, for example), you may want to re-examine whether it's the right one to use. The `isalnum` function may be more apt but it also depends on your use case. You may need to preserve spaces as well.
>
> Otherwisethingsmaygetverymessyandhardtoread :-)

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion to use and source and destination really helps as well.

Answer (score 1):

*You made a mistake in the function **stripPunctuators**.*

> In **FOR LOOP** You used :

```
str[j] = str[j+1];
```

> The above statement is wrong because, same variable of the loop shouldn't be used in both the sides of the statement while running in a For Loop.

*Try changing*

```
str[j] = str[j+1] TO str[i] = str[j+1]
```

> The Code is

```
void stripPunctuators(char *str){

int i, j, len = strlen(str);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
 if (!isalpha(str[i]))
 {
   for (j = i; j < len; j++)
   {
     str[i] = str[j + 1];
   }
   len--;
 }
 str[i] = tolower(str[i]);} }
```

> ***Try Using the above code, the problem will be solved.***